# when to use $_SESSION in php

Tags: php

Can someone tell me why do i need to use session in

```
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1';
}
else {

}
```

why not just variable?

```
<?php


session_start();

$page = "index.php";

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('products') or die (mysql_error());

if(isset($_GET['add'])){

$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1';
}
else {

}

function products(){
$query = 'SELECT id,name,description,price FROM products WHERE quantity>0 ORDER BY id ASC';
 $get = mysql_query($query);

if($get == 0){

    echo "There are no products to display";
}
else{

    while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
        echo '<p>'.$get_row['name'].'<br/>'.$get_row['description'].'<br/>'.$get_row['price'].'<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'">Add</a>'.'</p>';

        }
    }

}
```

?>

Comment: Because you want your cart to persist across requests surely?

Comment: A session variable will be available the whole time a session is active. A "normal" variable will not persist through pages while a session variable does.

Comment: thanks but is it possible to store it in a variable? like, is it not gonna give an error?

Comment: Do **NOT** use the `mysql_xxx()` functions for your database access. PHP deprecated those functions a long time ago, and they have now been removed entirely from the latest PHP release. If you're still using `mysql_query()`, then you're more than a decade behind established best-practice recommendations, let alone compatibility with current PHP versions.

Comment: what should i use then? mysqli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information between page requests. Session IDs are normally sent to the browser via session cookies and the ID is used to retrieve existing session data. The absence of an ID or session cookie lets PHP know to create a new session, and generate a new session ID.

source: [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)